# ModelState.IsValid returns False even if the required property is valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

ModelState.IsValid returns false even if the properties with Required annotation have valid values. I logged the string representation of the object and it shows that the Username and Password is not empty.

User Model

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
         return $"Username: {Username}, Password: {Password}";
    }


}
```

Controller

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger<User> _logger;
    [BindProperty]
    public User AuthUser { get; set; }

    public AuthController(ILogger<User> logger, UserContext context)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View(new User());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnURL = null)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
             _logger.LogInformation(AuthUser.ToString());
             //Executes this block even if Username and Password has data
        }


    }
```

Comment: You get ModelState error as expected that you are posting a `User` object from View to Controller, while your Controller (the Login POST method) is expected to receive a string value. Your  Login (Post) method should be expected to receive a `User` object.

Comment: `ModelState` gives you the state of the default model binder.  In your post request you're not accepting a `User` object. If you don't accept a user object in the post request, the default model binder can't update with your expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View(new User());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(User model,string returnURL = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
             _logger.LogInformation(model.ToString());
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for a long time and finally I found it. In my case, it was the Id field :)

Just place a breakpoint and check your ModelState in runtime and go to this section :

ModelState -> Root -> Children

and you will see all valid and invalid Keys

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There may be issues with int fields.
In your case, that could be the Id field.

As we know, integer can not be null and if in view page we have set its value to empty, it will be marked as invalid in the ModelState in the post method. Because, int can not be null/empty.

Comment: A little tip:
In order to prevent such errors, you can define id like this:

 public long? Id { get; set; }